# Refreshing JComponent to make a count down isn't working

Tags: java, swing, refresh, components, repaint

I made this sample to count down thirty seconds on a java dialog message. Somehow the message component isn't refreshing and I couldn't understand until now why. If time is being updated and the component repainted it should be working. I tryed to repaint both components `message.repaint()` and also `messageFrame.repaint()` but none works.

The code below is ready to run.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Chronometer {


    private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);


public Chronometer(){

    double timeToNext = System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000;
        double timeDifference = 30000;

    JFrame messageFrame = new JFrame();
    messageFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    messageFrame.setTitle("Warning");
    JLabel message = new JLabel("Preventing connection block. Next query in " + timeDifference/1000 + " seconds.");
    messageFrame.setSize(1000,1000);
    messageFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    addComponent(messageFrame, message, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    messageFrame.setVisible(true);

    while(timeDifference > 0){
        timeDifference = timeToNext - System.currentTimeMillis();
        messageFrame.repaint();
        //message.repaint();
    }
}


private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy,
        int gridwidth, int gridheight, int anchor, int fill) {

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0,
    anchor, fill, INSETS, 0, 0);

      container.add(component, gbc);
      }


public static void main(String[] args){

Chronometer c = new Chronometer();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You going at it the wrong way. Using a while loop within a constructor is a bad idea.
You should instead use a Timer as this is exactly what a Chronometer is. I took you code and rewrote it quickly with a timer and to make use of the observer pattern to update the label.

Use a controller that implements the Observer interface.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Controller implements Observer {
    private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    private Chronometer chrono = new Chronometer();
    private final JLabel message = new JLabel();

    public Controller() {
        final JFrame messageFrame = new JFrame("Warning");

        messageFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        messageFrame.setSize(1000,1000);
        messageFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        addComponent(messageFrame, message, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

        messageFrame.setVisible(true);

        chrono.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void startChrono(int delay) {
        chrono.startCountDown(delay);
    }

    public void refreshLabel() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                message.setText("Preventing connection block. Next query in " + chrono.getTime()/1000 + " seconds.");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        refreshLabel();
    }

    private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0,anchor, fill, INSETS, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }
}
```

Create a chronometer class with a timer:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Chronometer extends Observable {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final int startTime = 30000;
    private int time = 30000;

    public void decreaseTime() {
        if (time > 0) time--;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void reset() {
        time = startTime;
    }

    public void startCountDown(int delay) {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                decreaseTime();
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
            }
        }, delay,1);
    }
}
```

Finally start your controller

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Controller().startChrono(1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will analasy this code, I was just implementing a runnable cos when I try to do this on my main programm the update of the component becomes blank hehe you just came up with the other part the solution I was building hahaha ty

Comment: Now, this is almost right. Just needs to be modified to create and access the swing components in the event dispatch thread - and preferably to use swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of the general purpose timer for a convenient way to do the label updating too in the EDT.

Comment: @kiheru i just wanted to point out that it was a bad idea to use a while loop in a constructor and added a timer to his code to demonstrate. If you use a swing timer or another timer does not matter because that is an implementation detail, it's the principle that counts in this case.

Comment: It would be just an implementation detail if modifying swing objects outside the EDT was not a bug. I called it "almost right" because using a timer instead of busy looping is the correct idea.

Comment: @kiheru And what does it matter what timer you use if the purpose is just to count down from 30 to 0? You start talking about an EDT, what is an EDT?

Comment: EDT == [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). The type of the timer matters because changing the label must be done in the EDT. A swing timer will do it automatically, for `java.util.Timer` it would be necessary to use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: Well it's pretty simple, the only object which is updated is the time variable in the Chronometer class. The chronometer should that do that so Timer.Util is appropriate in this case. I rewrote the code to show you what i mean, no swing timer involved but instead the observer pattern is used which is what you have to use in such cases.

Comment: That is **not** the only update. The problem is calling `message.setText()` outside the EDT (Via the observer now, directly before. Check with `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` if you are unsure). That is not thread safe. It "usually" seems to work, but the more complex a gui program gets, the more likely it is to break in seemingly random ways unless it obeys the threading rule. Wrap that call with `invokeLater()` and it is fine. Similarly the creation of the GUI should be done in the EDT.

Comment: There we go, this should be good. Thanks for the tips kiheru.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the JLabel text manually I think. Try changing your while loop like so:

```
 while(timeDifference > 0) {
     timeDifference = timeToNext - System.currentTimeMillis();
     message.setText("Preventing connection block. Next query in " + timeDifference/1000 + " seconds.");
 }
```

Comment: I dont think a while loop is the way to tackle this problem, check my answer.